# How do I import .csv file from Google Docs into javascript

Tags: javascript, documentation, csv

Another newbie question. I would like to be able to import a .CSV spreadsheet from Google Docs into javascript so that I can parse it, and then extract the bits I want into an array.

I can do the second bit, but what I can't work out is what to write to pull in the .csv using the Google Docs 
URL so that it's available as a string to process.

And if there's a better way method, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to learn about JSONP and the [Google APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/samples.html)

Answer (score 4):

Not a javascript expert but if you want to retrieve your spreadsheet in CSV form you can issue an HTTP GET request to the following url:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=[your_doc_key]&output=csv
```

The key of your spreadsheet is the same you can see in the url when you are editing it using Google docs interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: jquery-csv 0.7 (Beta)

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference